# JUnit - java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "..." because "this.modelMapper" is null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

I've been learning Java for about 4 months, so please excuse basic mistakes.

I'm trying to unit test a method from my Service layer:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<StudentDto> getStudentList() {
        List<Student> tempList = studentDAO.getStudentList();

        List<StudentDto> tempListStudentDto = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Student theStudent: tempList) {
            tempListStudentDto.add(convertToDto(theStudent));
        }

        return tempListStudentDto;
    }
```

With this @Test:

```
    // JUnit test for getStudentList()
    @Test
    @DisplayName("getStudentList()")
    public void givenStudentList_whenGettingList_thenReturnList() {
        // given -precondition
        BDDMockito.given(studentDao.getStudentList())
                .willReturn(List.of(newStudentOne, newStudentTwo));

        // when - behaviour that we are going to test

        List<StudentDto> studentList = studentService.getStudentList();

        // then - verify the output
        assertAll(
                () -> org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(studentList).isNotNull(),
                () -> org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(studentList).size().isEqualTo(2)
        );
```

And I'm constantly getting this error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.getConfiguration()" because "this.modelMapper" is null

Could you please help me here or tell me how to convert the Student class to DTO in a testable way?

I've googled the issue and tried all of the suggestions, but could not make it to work.

Answer (score -1):

To help answer this question, we need to see which properties you declared and which annotations you put. Usually the error is in them, either you forgot to initialize the property, or you put the wrong annotation, mixing up the annotations of unit tests and integration tests.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.
Please do not comment in the answer and take the tour and read How to Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer